# How can I tell what has changed in a Comprehensive Rules update?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As an example, the Comp Rules were updated February 1, 2012.  I know that a reference to "Fateful Hour" was added to 207.2c since I know to search for fateful hour, but how do I know what else changed?  Does Wizards of the Coast release an official list of changes when they make a revision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They put an article in their website written by the current Rules Manager (the main authority in Wizards for Magic rules).

This is the one that corresponds to the [February 1, 2012 rules update](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/179a&page=1).

If you search for more articles by the same author, you'll find the articles for older rules updates. Searching for articles of previous Rules Managers is trickier.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe they release a full changelog every time they make a change to the rules, because most of the time, they're minor patches, like adding/removing creature types, or adding a few new block mechanics.

However, when big changes happen, such as Sixth Edition or M10, they usually discuss those changes in detail, in form of an article, such as [this](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/46a&page=1).

I do believe though that a full diff of rules changes would be pretty awesome for the rules lawyers among us. A website doing this could be fully automated, just checking the rules in txt format once a day or so.

**EDIT: Googling a bit revealed [this gem](http://yawgatog.com/resources/rules-changes/), which seems to be exactly what I had in mind: A privately maintained, exact changelog between rules versions**

Answer (score 0):

Wizards releases what they call Update Bulletins. Within this update bulletin, is a section called **Comprehensive Rulebook Changes**. You can search for the latter, and eliminate most other update bulletins not referring to the rules changes.
[Search for comprehensive rulebook changes](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=010753050335830773696%3ases62ofhwsq&ie=UTF-8&name=sa&q=Comprehensive%20rulebook%20changes#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=Comprehensive%20rulebook%20changes&gsc.page=1)

Even if Wizards didn't release this list of changes, you could use something like the Internet wayback machine, and a text difference tool (meld, fd, etc.) to find the changes yourself.